# Is it correct random generator function?

Tags: c++

I use this function to generate random integer.

```
int rnd(int min, int max)
{
    static int srand(time(0));
    return min + rand() % max;
}
```

Is it right? May be better to move `srand(time(0));` to the main function? Like this:

```
int rnd(int min, int max){
    return min + rand() % max;
}
int main(){
srand(time(0));
..............
}
```

Comment: It's either way ok, in later case, srand may be unnecessarily intialized even you don't call rnd at all, to be precise use (max - min + 1) in denominator

Comment: @DebasishJana No! That's wrong what you're saying!

Comment: `static int srand(time(0));` does not call `srand`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, what is wrong here? A static data gets initialized when the encompassing function is called

Comment: BTW, library random (in C++) provide cleaner way to generate random number  (as `std::uniform_int_distribution`).

Comment: the static init is wrong. It could be `static int somevar = srand(time(0));` but only if srand returned some dummy value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first version does not do what you intend:

```
int rnd(int min, int max)
{
    static int srand(time(0));
    return min + rand() % max;
}
```

This does not call the function `srand`. It declares a static variable of type `int` and assigns it the value of `time(0)`. Like `int a(42);` (or in C++11 `int a{42};`) declares an integer and sets it to `42`.

---

Definitely use the second variant. It also makes live much easier, if you want to have another function for creating random values in a different way.

---

Additionally I strongly recommend to use `std::random` (or `boost::random` if you are not allowed to use C++11 for some obscure reason).

Comment: +1 for mentioning `<random>`. `rand()` is discouraged nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely. You are now not calling the function but creating an integer variable named `srand` instead which shadows the global `srand()`.

It does not help to re-seed the random generator each time -- it would even return always the same value if called during the same second! Calling it just once in `main()` would be better.

Also it should probably be `min + rand() % (max - min + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

In general you only need to initialize the pseudorandom number generator once, so in the main function is a good idea.

I believe [Netscape once had a bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator_attack#Predictable_Netscape_seed) due to seeding the random number generator too often, which caused its SSL implementation to be more easily cracked.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it right?

If by that you mean "is it generating a random number?", the answer is **yes**.

If you mean "is it optimal?" then the answer is **no**. You only need to initialize the sequence of random number once.

> May be better to move srand(time(0)); to the main function

Maybe ... (you know what you need better than us).

What are you trying to achieve (that is, what are you using this random generator for)? If it is anything with financial data, online gambling application (or anything that takes/manages/costs money) it is not ok (nor is it to use srand and rand - you need something stronger).